# как правильно составить Query

Tags: grafana

Есть связка Elasticsearch + grafana. Стоить задача вытащить количество уникальных сообщений вида *"<11>pmchal: error: [ONT0/128] Can't get configuration for ONT ELTX6215C3C4, code 0,5"*. и представить в виде таблицы. Запрос составил так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и вроде бы работает, но при таком запросе в результат попадают и другие сообщения в которых есть слова *"configuration", "for" , "Can't get"*

Подскажите, как правильно составить запрос, чтобы не было лишнего? И можно ли как то "обезать" начало *<11>pmchal: error:*?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса